# Evaluating arithmetic string in Haskell- debugging

Tags: string, debugging, haskell, arithmetic-expressions

I'm attempting to take in a string, evaluate, and output the answer. For example: if the input is the string "2*(3+10)" then the output should be the int 26

At the moment, It isn't working. I'm having problems with white space. If there is white space in the code input, I get `***Exception: Char.digitToInt: not a digit ' '`. If there is NO whitespace in the input i get `*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large`

```
import Data.Char

parseExpr :: String -> Int
parseExpr str = start(trim (str))

trim :: [Char] -> [Char]
trim xs = [ x | x <- xs, not (isSpace x)]


start :: [Char] -> Int
start xs = expression xs 0


expression :: [Char] -> Int -> Int 
expression xs i  
    |(xs !! (((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)+1)) == '+' = (multiply xs ((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)) + (multiply xs ((basic xs (i+2) (-1))!! 0))
    |(xs !! (((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)+1)) == '-' = (multiply xs ((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)) - (multiply xs ((basic xs (i+2) (-1))!! 0))
    |otherwise = multiply xs i


multiply :: [Char] -> Int -> Int 
multiply xs i  
     | (xs !! (((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)+1)) == '*' = (power xs ((basic xs i (-1))!! 0)) * (power xs ((basic xs (i+2) (-1))!! 0))
     | (xs !! (((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)+1)) == '/' = (power xs ((basic xs i (-1))!! 0)) `div` (power xs ((basic xs (i+2) (-1))!! 0))
     |otherwise = power xs i


power :: [Char] -> Int -> Int 
power xs i
    | (xs !! (((basic xs i (-1))!! 1)+ 1)) == '^' = (((basic xs i (-1))!! 0) ^ ((basic xs (i+2) (-1))!! 0))
    |otherwise = (basic xs i (-1)) !! 0


basic :: [Char] -> Int -> Int -> [Int]
basic xs i pnum 
    | pnum > (-1) && (isDigit(xs !!(i+1))) = basic xs (i+1) (pnum*10 + (digitToInt(xs !! i)))
    | isDigit(xs !! i ) && isDigit(xs !!(i+1)) = basic xs (i+1) (digitToInt (xs !! i))
    | pnum > (-1) && not (isDigit(xs !!(i+1))) = [pnum, i] -- + digitToInt(xs !! i)
    | xs !! i == '-' = [(-(basic xs (i+1)(-1)) !! 0) , i] -- may want to delete if add/sub can handle
    | xs !! i == '(' = [(expression xs (i+1)), i]
    | xs !! i == ')' = [(expression xs (i+1)), i] --This may not work here
    | otherwise =  [digitToInt (xs !! i), i]
```

Comment: This kind of task tends to be simpler if you separate parsing from evaluation. Define a data type like `data Expr = Value Int | Add Expr Expr | Must Expr Expr`, parse `2*(3+10)` to `Multiply (Add (Value 3) (Value 10))` with `parse :: String -> Expr`, then evaluate the parsed expression with `evaluate :: Expr -> Int`. All the hard work of dealing with parentheses, whitespace, and operator precedence gets isolated to your `parse` function.

Comment: @chepner Agreed, and I'd use `parse :: String -> Maybe Expr` instead, so that syntax errors can be reported.

Comment: @chepner does that solve the issue or is this a stylistic idea? Also, could you give an example of how to do that/what you mean?

Comment: @chi: Wouldn't `parse :: String -> Either String Expr` be better since you can put an error message in `Left` as early as possible?

Comment: @Guvante Yes, sure.